# Linkedin Login API returning Status 500: Internal Server Error

Tags: passport.js, linkedin-api, passport-linkedin

been stuck for a while trying to implement **LinkedIn Login** using the `passport` framework on nodejs with `passport-linkedin-oauth2` strategy.

These are my configurations for the strategy on nodejs

```
const strategy =  new LinkedInStrategy(
    {
      clientID: LINKEDIN_KEY,
      clientSecret: LINKEDIN_SECRET,
      callbackURL: BASE_URL + "/auth/linkedin/callback",
      scope: ["r_emailaddress", "r_liteprofile"],
    },
    (
      accessToken,
      refreshToken,
      profile,
      done
    ) => {
      process.nextTick(() => {
        return done(null, profile);
      });
    }
  )
```

The callback route defined so:

```
router.get(
    "/auth/linkedin/callback",
    passport.authenticate("linkedin",{
        successRedirect: "/",
        failureRedirect: "/auth/linkedin",
    })
);
```

In the dev environment on http://localhost:3000, this works perfectly fine - [image showing redirection success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1g8V.png). After a login success, I get redirected to `localhost:3000`.
In production however, hosted at  https://www.(example_website).com, the redirection throws a code 500 internal server error - [image showing redirection failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKVhM.png).

I'm lost as to why the issue is happening for the production site. Really appreciate any clues or help to debug this!

Comment: Did you register your production redirect url in linkedIn ? Not sure about linkedIn but OAuth flow is requires that.

Comment: Hi, yes i did! Thats why it was able to redirect to the callback url after the login success, but somehow the callback itself is failing.

Comment: @Melina-laimon did you find a solution? I am encountering the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved just add my application URL in linkedin app setting
my apps > Settings > Additional settings > [url]